# Jquery Datepiocker Css removes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am developing an app in which we are highlighting dates in different colors by dynamically applying css and are using jquery mobile datepicker but when user click on any date the dynamically applied css got removed.

we used important tag in css but the class which are applied in datepicker library remains and the classes which are applied dynamically removes when user click on date

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please paste some workable sample code so that it is easier help

Comment: Reapply class on click? `!important` only works when deciding which rule takes precedence, it won't stop code from changing it.

Comment: I am using this to add and remove class from cells of datepciker $(cell).parent('td').removeClass('ovulationIcon');
  $(cell).removeClass('ovulation');
  $(cell).addClass('fertilityStartDate');   also when i re apply class on click it blinks and classes takes time to reapply that doesn't look nice